# Lightning Design System, how to start development?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, lightning-design-system

I am trying to learn LDS development and am using [this resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_framework.htm) to start.

Unfortunately, I am stuck [HERE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/qs_aotp_app_step2_cmp.htm) (I have an org with my own namespace, I have copied over the Lightning component and set its style) and I have no idea how to do the rest of the stuff.

So a few questions :

1. How do I "preview" what I made?
2. Is there an easier guide than the one I linked?
3. Can anyone explain to me in simple words just what mess I've gotten myself into?

I just CANNOT wrap my head around what I'm supposed to be doing in that documentation.

Comment: [Trailhead's Lightning Components Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com//en/module/lex_dev_lc_basics) may help you.

Answer (score 5):

The best way I would suggest to learn is through Trailhead, it will provide step by step guide on implementation. This is where you can start [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/module/lightning_design_system). This is a basic trailhead for LDS.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: also, what is a scoping class?

Comment: ^ nvm, figured it out :D wow i almost gave up back there... and the answer as so simple... and so hard to find... Salesforce has really bad documentation sometimes.